# NullpointerException Arquillian test Ask

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

hello guys i'm new in arquillian test and i'm struggling with it. The issue here that I have a stateless service called `UserManagment` which implements `UserManagmentLocal` interface. When I try to inject it in the arquillian test I get `nullpointerException` any ideas ?

this is the test :

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class UserManagmentTest {

@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class,"test.jar")
    .addClasses(User.class,Admin.class,Customer.class,UserManagment.class,UserManagmentLocal.class)
    .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "persistence.xml")
    .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}

@Inject
private UserManagmentLocal userManagment;

@Test
public void should_create_greeting() throws UserNotFoundException {
assertEquals(2, userManagment.findAllUsers().size());
}
```

and this is the service :

```
@Stateless(name="userManagment")
@LocalBean
public class UserManagment implements UserManagmentLocal {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MagasinElectronique-ejb")
EntityManager em;

static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserManagment.class);

@Override
public List<User> findAllUsers() throws UserNotFoundException {
    try {
        TypedQuery<User> q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u", User.class);
        return q.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        logger.error("No User Found",e);
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }

}
```

Exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:433)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:128)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
>       at services.UserManagmentLocal$2004037709$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.findAllUsers(Unknown Source)
>       at arquillian.UserManagmentTest.should_create_greeting(UserManagmentTest.java:55)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:379)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.protocol.local.LocalContainerMethodExecutor.invoke(LocalContainerMethodExecutor.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:109)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:136)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:372)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:246)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:260)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:324)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.execute(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:99)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.on(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:72)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:159)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:317)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:205)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:219)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:167)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>TheGenie</groupId>
    <artifactId>MagasinElectronique</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>MagasinElectronique-ejb</artifactId>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Startarquillian -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Endarquillian -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Startarquillian -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Endarquillian -->
    </plugins>

</build>
<!-- Startarquillian -->

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<!-- Endarquillian -->
```

Comment: post your Exception

Comment: done i've added the Exception trace up